# Point of contact to learn Atharvana veda?

Tags: rituals, practice, atharva-veda

Where can we find the guru who can teach Atharvana Veda?

Is it applicable for Brahmins?

This question is not about black magic. But to understand that and perform white magic.

I know this is not something like watching udemy tutorials for knowledge improvements. But wanted to explore this as such practices are more now. Resolutions are less.

What are the qualities does one should have to learn this? I don't know whether this question will be deleted or answered generously. Attempting to find sensible answer.